# Python: return float 1.0 as int 1 but float 1.5 as float 1.5

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

In Python is there a way to turn `1.0` into a integer `1` while the same function ignores `1.5` and leaves it as a `float`?

Right now, `int()` will turn `1.0` into `1` but it will also round `1.5` down to `1`, which is not what I want.

Comment: one way could be to check the float using `is_integer()` if that passes, convert it to `int`?

Comment: Do you want to make only floats with `0` after decimal mark back to integer form ?

Comment: Floats are approximations, `1.0` could actually be `1.00000000000001` or `0.999999999999`.

Comment: Note that because of duck typing, this passage you want to achieve is probably out of place or useless, depending on context.

Comment: Please specify your exact requirements in words/rules rather than just with a single example!

Comment: @Barmar Could. But 1.0 is expressable exactly in float, unlike 0.3, 0.7 or 1.1.

Comment: @glglgl That's true if you are dealing with the *literal* `1.0`, but a calculation that you *expect* to return exactly 1.0 may not.

Comment: @chepner Well, expectations are surely not always fulfilled. But you are true, one might indeed surprised in these cases. 0.5 * 2 clearly returns 1.0, but .4 + .6 might not, and that can be surprising to the unaware user.

Comment: you should provide more context, what are you trying to achieve? there might be straight-forward solution to your original problem

Comment: `def f(x): if x == 1.0: return 1 else return 1.5`

Comment: Do you need a string or a numeric value?

Answer (score 80):

Continuing from the comments above:

Using [`is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

**Example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)**:

```
>>> (1.5).is_integer()
False
>>> (1.0).is_integer()
True
>>> (1.4142135623730951).is_integer()
False
>>> (-2.0).is_integer()
True
>>> (3.2).is_integer()
False
```

**INPUT**:

```
s = [1.5, 1.0, 2.5, 3.54, 1.0, 4.4, 2.0]
```

**Hence**:

```
print([int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in s])
```

Wrapped in a function:

```
def func(s):
    return [int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in s]

print(func(s))
```

If you do not want any `import`:

```
def func(s):
    return [int(x) if x == int(x) else x for x in s]

print(func(s))
```

Using [`map()`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) with [`lambda`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html) function and the iter `s`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: int(x) if x.is_integer() else x, s)))
```

**OR**

```
print(list(map(lambda x: int(x) if int(x) == x else x, s)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[1.5, 1, 2.5, 3.54, 1, 4.4, 2]
```

Comment: If anyone is curious about about the limits of is_integer() and how far away from 1.0 a floating point number can be and still be considered an integer, I wrote a short script to find the limit. It's a very small number, much more precision than I have ever needed for anything. (1.0 + 1.1102230246251566636831481088739149080825883254353483864385054857848444953560829162597656251e-16).is_integer() returns False, but (1.0 + 1.1102230246251566636831481088739149080825883254353483864385054857848444953560829162597656250e-16).is_integer() returns True.

Comment: @JoshDavis That's just about rounding to `1.0` vs. `1.0 + sys.float_info.epsilon`.

Comment: All solutions I see here, based on ```is_integer```, will fail miserably if they receive an integer value, because integers doesn't have that method. To be safe, something like this will help: ```to_int = lambda x: int(x) if float(x).is_integer() else x```

Comment: @accdias: That won't always work either, since `float` has representational limits while  `int` does not. Passing `x = 1 << 1024` will cause your code to die with an `OverflowError`. So now you've got additional checks for safety, or exception handling.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, that is true but I'm pretty sure most of people will be never reaching the ```1 << 1024``` limit, if ever. On the other hand, I think it is much more feasible to see someone trying to do ```2 .is_integer()``` than ```float(1<<1024)```. Good info anyway.

Comment: You could check if the second element of `.as_integer_ratio()` is 1, as this is also defined on ints (at least on python3.8+).

Answer (score 32):

In case your goal is to convert numbers to a concise string, you could simply use `'%g'` ("General Format") for [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> '%g' % 1.0
'1'
>>> '%g' % 1
'1'
>>> '%g' % 1.5
'1.5'
>>> '%g' % 0.3
'0.3'
>>> '%g' % 0.9999999999
'1'
```

You can specify the desired accuracy:

```
>>> '%.15g' % 0.999999999999999
'0.999999999999999'
>>> '%.2g' % 0.999
'1'
```

Comment: This is great but I had a query yesterday that for some reason I couldn't ask, this would turn `0.9` to `1` but considering one only wants `1.0` to `1` or `2.0` to `2` and not `0.9` to `1` or `1.9` to `2`. Do we have a workabout in that case? cheers!

Comment: @DirtyBit: Sorry, I really don't understand the question. `'%g' % 0.9` is `'0.9'` and `'%g' % 2.0` is `'2'`. Floats are displayed as ints only if they're really close to an int, e.g. `0.9999995`. But not `0.9` or `0.99`

Comment: exactly: `print('%g' % 0.9999999999)   # 1` but let's say the req. was to only have `1` if it was `1.0` and not `0.9999999999`?

Comment: @DirtyBit: You can specify the desired accuracy : `'%.15g' % 0.999999999999999` is `'0.999999999999999'` and `'%.2g' % 0.999`is `'1'`. From this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) : *Rounding error is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation*.

Comment: that is fascinating but still gives a little sense of hardcoding. no? Nevertheless, you have my upvote!

Comment: @DirtyBit: I'm not sure what you mean with hardcoding. A float cannot be an integer, it can only seem to be close enough to an int : `1.0000000000000001.is_integer() #=> True` There's always an epsilon involved, even if it is hidden.

Comment: Best answer since this is the only valid use case for what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: @jpmc26: Thanks. That's what I thought too : there's no need to selectively convert floats and ints otherwise.

Answer (score 14):

[`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) is a method on floats that returns whether or not the float represents an integer.

You can just use this function I made called `to_int`, that uses `is_integer` to check whether it represents an integer (e.g. `1.0`) or not (e.g. `1.5`).

If it represents an integer, return `int(a)`, otherwise just return it's original value.

As you see, I am not using `elif` or `else` because `return` returns only once:

```
def to_int(a):
   if a.is_integer():
      return int(a)
   return a

print(to_int(1.5))
print(to_int(1.0))
```

Output:

```
1.5
1
```

Answer (score 5):

Python floats are approximations, so something that *prints* as `1.0` is not necessarily exactly `1.0`. If you want to see if something is *approximately* an integer, use a sufficiently small epsilon value.

```
EPSILON = 0.0001 # Make this smaller or larger depending on desired accuracy

def func(x):
  if abs(x - round(x)) < EPSILON:
    return round(x)
  else:
    return x
```

In general, if you're checking whether a float is `==` to something, that tends to be a code smell, as floating point values are inherently approximate. It's more appropriate in general to check whether a float is near something, within some epsilon range.

Comment: While most floating point values are approximations, there are many integers that can be represented exactly. A 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point number (as used in Python and other languages) can represent exactly any signed integer that fits in 53 bits or less. Such integers can be converted 1 to 1 between a 64-bit float and 64-bit integer assuming the integer value could be represented with as little as 53 bits. Addition, subtraction, and multiplication that stays within 53-bits of integer space should yield identical results per IEEE 754 spec.

Comment: @penguin359 While I agree that integers *can* be represented exactly in floating point, if you're in the situation that OP is in, you need to ask yourself how close to an integer is "close enough" for your purpose. Is `1.0 + 1e-16` "close enough"? Is `1.0 + 2e-16`? It's an important question, as IEEE 754-based "is integer" methods will treat them differently, and you may or may not want to consider `1.0 + 2e-16` "not an integer" while saying `1.0 + 1e-16` is one. -- Having an explicit epsilon (versus the implicit one from IEEE 754) makes your desires clearer.

Comment: A comment seeming best at this answer: Setting an epsilon works as in the example provided works fine.  Alternatively, especially if dealing with cents (currencies in general), I found it more useful to change from Python's default of binary representation to decimal one, as provided by module decimal (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html).  The difference, for example in a loop iterating from -1 to +1 in increments of 0.1 is either passing very close to 0, or right at 0.0 -- without need for an epsilon set (how would you deal with -1.3877787807814457e-16 currency units?).

Comment: "so something that prints as 1.0 is not necessarily exactly 1.0" That depends on the version of python. In modern python3 (IIRC since python 3.2) a float that prints as 1.0 is exactly 1.0. In older versions of python it may not be. Try "print (float(numpy.nextafter(1.0,2)))" to see what happens on your version.

Answer (score 1):

for list of numbers:

```
def get_int_if_possible(list_of_numbers):
    return [int(x) if x == int(x) else x for x in list_of_numbers]
```

for one number:

```
def get_int_if_possible(number):
    return int(number) if number == int(number) else number
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple thing you could do is use the modulo operator:

```
if (myFloat % 1 == 0) // Number is an int
else // numer is not an int
```

**EDIT: Python code**

```
if myFloat % 1 == 0:
  # myFloat is an integer.
else:
  # myFloat is NOT an integer
```

Answer (score -3):

What I used to do in the past in C++ is, lets say you have these variables:

```
float x = 1.5;
float y = 1.0;
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
if(x == (int)x) 
    return 1;
else return 0;
```

This will return 0 because 1.5 is not equal to 1

```
if(y == (int)y) 
    return 1;
else return 0;
```

This will return 1 because 1.0 is equal to 1

Of course your question is about Python and the function `is_integer()` should work great, I just thought some people might find this useful.

Comment: The question was to convert a float to int whenever the float in question has an integer value. AFAIK this is not possible in C++, because you cannot return different values from a function.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp you could have a `union` though.

Comment: And also you could set another integer variable and save the float there if the condition above is met

Comment: The digression on C++ isn't really relevant. You can do the same thing in Python: `foo = lambda x: int(x) if int(x) == x else x`. (Or in Python 3.8, to avoid the duplicate call to `int`, `lambda x: y if (y:=int(x)) == x else x`.

Comment: @chepner I tried `foo = lambda x: int(x) if int(x) == x else x` the very moment I wrote the answer above, for some reason it did not work for me in 3.6. Any clue?

Comment: @DirtyBit None at all, because I don't know what you mean by "did not work".

Comment: @chepner somthing like `print(list(filter(lambda x: int(x) if x.is_integer() else x, s)))` returns `[1.5, 1.0, 2.5, 3.54, 1.0]`?

Comment: `filter` doesn't modify the values in the list; the function is just a predicate that decides whether or not to *select* the original value for its output. Use `map` instead.

Comment: @chepner, that is what happens when you miss you caffeine shot. Indeed, map it was. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

```
def your_function(i):
  if i.is_integer():
    return int(i)
  else:
    return float(i)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be very helpful if you could add on what is happening in there and how does it solve the problem, in order to increase the lifetime of your answer and to attract the users looking for the similar solution.

Comment: strings and floats have a function called is_integer, which returns true if it's a number, and false if anything else (including floats). So, if it's an int, return it as an int. Anything else (it's a float) and return it as a float.

Comment: @ xcrafter_40 not as a comment, you may edit your answer to add the explanation. :)

Comment: what was the other downvote for?

Answer (score -3):

`divmod` alternative:

```
def f(x):
    return x if divmod(x, 1)[1] else int(x)
```