# Add floats passed as strings

Tags: python

I am writing a python code where I provide 2 strings as input and the program should give me sum of those numbers as response in string format.

```
def sum(s1, s2):
    return str(float(s1) + float(s2))
```

This works fine if my input s1 and s2 are small float values example 3.6, 2.1 gives me 5.7

But I have some issues here:

**case 1:**

IF input is s1=3, s2 = 5, I want output as 8, but the program gives me 8.0

**case 2:**

If input is s1=100000000000000000000000000000001 and s2 = 100000000000000000000000000000002, I want  output as 200000000000000000000000000000003, but the program gives me `2e+32`

What changes I have to do to this code? can you please help me.

I am using Python 3.

Comment: Regarding floats, you can use the `float.is_integer()` method and round to nearest integer if that is true. You can also use string formatting to output a consistently formatted number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617/format-numbers-to-strings-in-python

Comment: The reason you're getting floats back, is because you're setting them to floats. Floats also use notation for large/small numbers by default, so that is the reason for getting `2e+32` instead of the numbers themselves. Change `float` to `int` instead and you should get the expected results.

Comment: @jakub when a `float` becomes large enough, `is_integer()` will *always* return true because of the limited precision of floating point.

Comment: @MarkRansom, can you please tell me how to add large values like `100000000000000000000000000000001 ` as mention in case 2 in my post

Comment: Either use `int` instead of `float` as suggested by @HampusLarsson, or use the extended precision offered by [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify, because you asked "add floats" and you are casting the inputs to floats, but both of your examples are integers.

Comment: @GinoMempin, I added one more example with sample floats now. I added the special cases where my program is failing with sample data and expected outputs

Comment: It seems your question is not really about floats or floating-point precision (to which this was closed as duplicate), but more about string formatting or how to check if inputs are just plain integers, to avoid casting with `float()`. Because your main issue is that you cast everything as floats even if it isn't needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: return float 1.0 as int 1 but float 1.5 as float 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510485/python-return-float-1-0-as-int-1-but-float-1-5-as-float-1-5)

Comment: If this is homework, it could be that they wanted you to do long addition with the strings rather than converting to a numeric type first.

Comment: @MarkRansom, can you please tell me what it means long addition and how to do that?

Comment: I mean addition the way you learned as a kid, digit by digit.